# How do we distribute the javadb along with a jar so that it starts automatically when jar is run?

Tags: netbeans, jar, derby, javadb

I have created a project which needs a Javadb connection. What is the best way to distribute the javadb along with my jar? Is there a way to include it in the jar itself and start it when the jar is loaded? I am new to javadb, any help would be much appreciated.